# Same View in different view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view like this:

[image: Example:]
Each one of the buttons has an action to do when I click on them. And these buttons are changing dynamically through coding (if statements...), when I click some button it leads me to other different buttons values..also the Label is changing accordingly.

**ITS LIKE A QUIZ KIND OF THING!**

What I want is when I click a button , **It should lead me to a different layout of the (view buttons) ( area ).**

[image: Example OF Different layout]
I was thinking of adding a new view controller for each of what I want to do but this could mean 100 view controllers! I don't know if this is the right way to do it. Is there a better way?

Comment: I would store a `@IBOutlet` to each button. Then you can change the text, background/whatever you want for each button when you press one of them

Answer (score 0):

First I'd find similarities between your desired layouts. Implement one view controller making all of those similarities happen. For instance:

- show a label on top
- show four buttons below
- step back and forth between layouts
- show different kinds of buttons according to their description

Then you can initialize your view controller with a description of your questions, potential answers/buttons and behavior for each button. Let's say it's a quiz. So you create a class `Quiz` containing an array of `Question`s. Each `Question` contains the question it self as a `String` and a description for each of the four buttons. It could be the shape and color or a text/answer. And of course some sort of actions for the buttons. It could be just as mutch as a boolean state or a more complicated enum. You get the picture?
*(My answer seems to be as vague as your question.)*

In the end you'll have to write the whole description for your requirements. I'd write this into a txt, csv, plist, json (whatever is convenient writing and parsing for you) and parse it. That would be the fewest code.

Comment: I get what u say, but as for the description, how can I insert (shape,color ...etc ) inside the array and then link them to @IBOutlet and IBAction buttons separately?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. If you implement a UIButton subclass which e.g. can change it's shape, you can link it from your storyboard to `@IBOutlet`s by simply Ctrl-draging it from the storyboard onto your class. Same for `@IBAction`s, which you have to implament (the behavior). Alternativeley you could do it all in code, even removing and adding new buttons from and to your 4-button-layout.